Primeng : 'p-card' is not a known element
I have a problem that p-card isn't known even i declared it in the module
the error message:
X [ERROR] NG8001: 'p-card' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

this error shows when i do ng serve only!!!
it doesn't shown in the html code.
search-results.component.html:
<p-card header="Search Results" [style]="{ width: '300px' }">
  <ng-container *ngIf="searchResults.length > 0; else noResults">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let result of searchResults">{{ result }}</li>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #noResults>
    <div>No results found</div>
  </ng-template>
</p-card>

search-results.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SearchResultsComponent } from '../../components/search-results/search-results.component';
import { SharedModule } from 'primeng/api';
import { CardModule } from 'primeng/card'; // Import CardModule from PrimeNG


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SearchResultsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    CardModule
  ],
  exports: [
    SearchResultsComponent
  ]
})
export class SearchResultsModule { }


app.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './components/search/search.component';
import { SearchModule } from './modules/search/search.module';
import { SearchResultsComponent } from './components/search-results/search-results.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SearchModule
  ],
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


Angular version: 17.0.0
Primeng version: 17.13.0
All what i tried import CardModule to app.module.ts too but it didn't work

Have you tried to restart the Angular app? Meanwhile, I believe there is a typo error, as you are not importing the SearchResultsModule, but SearchModule in the AppModule.
